# What's the benefit of `npm audit signatures`?

Tags: node.js, security, npm

[Since npm v8.15.0](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-07-26-a-new-npm-audit-signatures-command-to-verify-npm-package-integrity/) there's a `npm audit signatures` command which will check each package's signature using npm's public key.

I don't understand why this is an extra layer of security. Given that npm is already using HTTPS and that it's already checking the package's integrity with the checksum from `package-lock.json`, what kind of attack does this prevent?

If the package was signed by the package author, it would be a different story.